# PHP rename(<from>, <to>) gives warning: "Is a directory"

Tags: php, file-io, rename

I have the following function:

```
function move($currentPath, $newPath)
{
    if (!$this->_createFolder($newPath))
        return false;

    if (!rename($currentPath, $newPath))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

where _createFolder() checks if the directory exists, and if it doesn't, creates it.  I'm consistently getting the following warning:

"rename(/home/user/folder/folder/app/webroot/img/listings/incomplete/15/0/picture1.png,/home/user/folder/folder/app/webroot/img/listings/130/picture1.png): Is a directory "

The file is successfully copied to the second directory, but is not deleted from the first directory.  rename() returns false and this warning is given.  I thought it might be something with permissions, but after trying a bunch of things I couldn't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is creating a folder using the `$newpath`

```
if (!$this->_createFolder($newPath))
        return false;
```

then `$newpath` becomes a directory.

Comment: Thanks! Stupid mistake - I had a function to extract the deepest directory and forgot to include it here.